# AngularJS not populating or inititializing select

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

In the AngularJS doc's, they reference [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/) from which I've derivded a simple jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mszczepaniak/0a1xbxm2/1/).

The entire HTML:

```
<body ng-app="demoApp">
<div ng-controller="demoController">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Select Category
      <select ng-model="selectedCategory"
              ng-options="cat as cat for cat in categories">
      </select>
    </td>
    The category selected is: {{selectedCategory}}
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Select CategoryId
      <select ng-model="selectedCatId"
              ng-options="ds as ds.id for ds in dataset">
      </select>
      The category id selected is: {{selectedCatId}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

The AngularJS controller:

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('demoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.categories = ["CAT1", "CAT2", "CAT3"];
  $scope.dataset = [
                    { "category": "CAT1", "id": "CAT_ID11" },
                    { "category": "CAT1", "id": "CAT_ID12" }
                   ];

  $scope.selectedCategory = categories[1];
  $scope.selectedCatId = $scope.dataset[1];
});
```

The result I'm seeing in the fiddle:

[image]

Besides not seeing the initialization, I'm not seeing the list items either and am not sure why.  What am I missing?

Comment: Post the code as text, not as images. Otherwise, we need to re-type it completely to show you how to fix it. And open your browser console: you'll see this error message: "ReferenceError: categories is not defined".

Comment: Good point about the code: revised with actual code.  Only did the fiddle as a simplification of the actual code and missed the browser feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

categories was not defined.
Golbal declaration-

```
var categories=["CAT1", "CAT2", "CAT3"];
```

Also categories is an array, So,

```
<select ng-model="selectedCategory"
                ng-options="cat for cat in categories">
        </select>
```

Check this fiddle-

http://jsfiddle.net/RahulB007/0a1xbxm2/2/

Comment: Scope issue with categories was the issue. "cat as cat for cat in categories" still works in my revised fiddle, but your version is more correct.

Comment: Probably should add `track by $index` to this. This will improve performance in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `$scope` for your categories, so the template does not have access to its value.

Just do something like:

```
 $scope.selectedCategory = $scope.categories[1];
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/0a1xbxm2/3/

Answer (score 1):

If you open the dev tools console in the browser, you'll see this error message:

> ReferenceError: categories is not defined

This means that your code tries to access a variable that is not defined. And indeed:

```
$scope.selectedCategory = categories[1];
```

should be

```
$scope.selectedCategory = $scope.categories[1];
```

During development, always leave the console opened.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle you have a working and non-working version.

The reason the one is not working is because angular is checking whether they are the same object, not if the values of the object are the same.

Pick a property on the object (typically a unique ID) and reference it via `track by`.

By doing this your markup would go from this:

```
ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
```

to this:

```
ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options track by opt.value">
```

[Here is your fiddle updated with my working addition](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/1015/)